# Can call throw but it is not marked with try and the error is not handled

Tags: swift

I am trying to run my Swift 1.0 syntax and am getting an error "Can call throw but it is not marked with try and the error is not handled.".

I tried adding a try / catch but a similar error occurs.

Here is the line of code:

```
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

I tried:

```
do {  
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary  
} catch _ {  
    //Error handling, if needed  
}
```

but I get "Can throw but was not marked as try".

Please help

Also doesnt work when I try this:

Comment: You have to implement do try catch error handling

Comment: It says immutable value was never used. Then I cant access that variable further down.

Comment: Add the code related to your problem, the line and the error description

Comment: It should be `let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...` (you are missing the `try` keyword inside your `do` block).

Comment: @dbus you have to pay attention at your variables life cycle. you can't have  access to jsonResult further down (outside the brackets)

Comment: @dbus just create a dictionary property at your view controller class to store the jsonResult